# How can I stop Maven from regenerating something if the generation-source has not changed?

Tags: java, maven, generated-code, generate

I want maven to skip generation of something (source, XML, XSDs - you name it - ) if the source of that thing has not changed.

Something like - **IF** the all files in src/main/x are younger than all files in target/generated-sources - **THEN** skip generation

Comment: Please show the pom file...

Comment: This is not a problem in the pom, which works as intended. It is a search for a solution to the question - and if you have to consider the question to conceptualize it (ie: you have never thought about the problem before) then you are unlikely to be able to provide an answer. This is a question to those have considered this before and have developed an as yet untried strategy, or have developed a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only solution I have come up with is to modify my code generators. This will work when the generator is mine, and will not when the generator is not (eg: wsimport or jaxb generators etc).

Ideally, I am looking for a way, or plugin, that will test all source files that are fed into the generators to see if any have changed. ie: Get the greatest LastChangedTime from all of the source files and compare that to the smallest (oldest) LastChangedTime in all of the generated sources.